# How do I fetch data (via GET) after some React state updates?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-state, react-state-management, react-typescript

When a user clicks one of the orderBy buttons (by name/email/date) - the user should get a new rendered result from the server (sending a new get request) - and the same goes for the page pagination.

setting `this.setState({ [thestate]: [newStateVar] })` doesn't do the job by itself ;)

**So is it "a good practice" to copy this line**:

```
    this.setState({
        tickets: await api.getTickets(this.state.currentOrder, this.state.page),
    });
```

from the `componentDidMount()` and re-write it? or even better - create a method that does only that - send a get request with all the vars - and call it whenever I need re-rendering. (and I can even remove these lines from `componentDidMount()` instead of rewriting lines.
Is this the right approach?

I always thought that whenever anything changes in the DOM (for example the orderBy btns `:active` class/style change) - all the things that can update get updated. Am I getting it right now? Wrong?

edit: Oh, and if you see something else worth mentioning to enlighten me - please do.

```
    import React from 'react';
    import './App.scss';
    import Pagi from './components/pagination/pagi';
    
    export type AppState = {
        tickets?: Ticket[],
        currentOrder: string,
        page: number,
    }
    
    const api = createApiClient();
    
    
    export class App extends React.PureComponent<{}, AppState> {
    
        state: AppState = {
            currentOrder: 'date',
            page: 1
        }
    
    
        async componentDidMount() {
            this.setState({
                tickets: await api....
            });
        }
    
        componentDidUpdate(pP:any, pS:any, sS:any) {
            if (this.state.page !== pS.page) {
                this.setState({ page: this.state.page })
            }
            if (this.state.currentOrder !== pS.currentOrder) {
                this.setState({ currentOrder: this.state.currentOrder })
            }
        }
          
 
        renderTickets = (tickets) => {
    
            const filteredTickets = tickets
                .filter(...);
    
            return (
                <ul> 
{showtkts}
                </ul>
            );
        }
    
    
        setOrder = (order:any) => {
            console.log(this.state.currentOrder)
    
            this.setState({
                currentOrder: order.target.value,
            });
        }
    
        setPage = (pageNum: number) => {
            this.setState({
                page: pageNum
            })
        }
    
        render() {
    
            const {tickets} = this.state;
    
            return (<main>
                
                    <span> Order by: </span>
                    <button value='name'  onClick={this.setOrder} className={ (this.state.currentOrder === 'name') ? 'selectedOrderItem' : '' }>
                        {/* <span role="img"  aria-label="name"></span>  */}
                        Name
                    </button>
                    <button value='email' onClick={this.setOrder} className={ (this.state.currentOrder === 'email') ? 'selectedOrderItem' : '' }>
                        {/* <span role="img"  aria-label="email"></span>  */}
                        Email
                    </button>
                    <button value='date'  onClick={this.setOrder} className={ (this.state.currentOrder === 'date') ? 'selectedOrderItem' : '' }>
                        {/* <span role="img"  aria-label="date"></span>  */}
                        Date
                    </button>
                </div>
    
                <div className='resultsCount'>
                    { tickets ? <div className='results'>Showing {tickets.length} results</div> : null }
                    { (this.state.hidden === 0) ? '' : ((this.state.hidden === 1) ? <div className='results'>(1 ticket is hidden</div> : <div className='results'>({this.state.hidden} hidden tickets </div>) }
                    { (this.state.hidden > 0) ? <div className='results showHiddenBtn' onClick={this.showHiddenTickets}>- restore) </div> : null  }
                </div>
    
                <div>
                    {getTkts here}
                </div>
                <Pagi pages={tickets ? tickets.length : 1}/>
        }
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Comment: Try codereview, but imho if it works it works, I personally like to keep a cached state and only fetch the newly requested data and append when required but sometimes that is extra work as well. KISS.

Comment: @Xorifelse I think it's a bad approach - there are some technologies built to work in a certain way. See Nicks comment. and obviously - if i continued with your advice I would be working wrong and not using react properly (and doing my interview task all wrong).

Comment: Can we agree to disagree? Let the frame, work for you right? I am not saying the question is not valid, its just not broken code and that is kind of expected here ([mcve]). But when working for a company you are "most of the time" required to write features, not perfect code. Leave your OCD behind, I puke from that statement but as of recently its how companies expect you to function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I fetch data (via GET) after some React state updates?

I think you are not approaching this correctly, the flow should be:

1. User action
2. fetch data
3. (in async) state update
4. render

and not the other way around where a render triggers a data fetch.

I recommend rethinking your component design instead of trying to make the flawed flow work with your current implementation.

See this codesandbox for an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-matsumoto-ti9ot?file=/src/App.js

**Edit:**

From comment below:

> Hi nick i have an other question reguarding to this. If i order results by email (that resets the page to 1 and tickets to []? how do i go from clicking a filter to fetch to state update if i need the state updated before fetching data.

Again, don't worry about timing the renders and updates manually, just manage your state and let react handle the udpates and renders, for example:

```js
const [data, setData] = useState();
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

const handleFetch = () => {
  fetchData().then((res) => {
    setData(res.data);
    setLoading(false);
  });
};
// Onload, fetch data and set loading to false when complete
useEffect(() => {
  handleFetch();
}, []);

return (
  <>
    {loading ? <div>Loading...</div> : <div>data: {data}</div>}
    <button onClick={handleFetch}>Click me to cause refetch data</button>
  </>
);
```

For your use case, you would either only display the data when loading is complete (effectively resetting data to `[]`), or display some sort of placeholder until the data is rendered. Instead of setting the states to empty, then fetching, then setting the states again.

Comment: Hi nick thanks for your answer, i feel like i missed something. If i refer what you said about my situation: 1. user changes page/orde  2. page/order state changes  3. fetch data  4. render.  how can I apply this kind of situation to the approach you mentioned? how can i swap between 2 and 3 ?

Comment: Ok i think i got it, just tell me if this is it.  1. user selects a new page/order.  2. onClick fetches new data, without having any state tracking the page number. 3.  a method fetches the new data and assign it to its respective state - which triggers,,,, 4. a new render :)

Comment: Yes thats exactly right. You want react to work *for you*, let it handle all the tasks between updating/rendering, you just set the state.

Comment: @W.Doch I edited my answer to include a codesandbox demo showing the flow I was mentioning.

Comment: Hi nick i have an other question reguarding to this. If i order results by email (that resets the page to 1 and tickets to `[]`? how do i go from clicking a filter to fetch to state update if i need the state updated before fetching data.